# SQL - which index will speed up the COUNT() query

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, indexing

I have a very simple Postgres database that looks like that (it's defined in Django but this doesn't matter):

```
class Country:
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    # Not important
    # name = models.TextField(nullable=False)

class City:
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    # name = models.TextField(nullable=False)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

class Street:
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    # name = models.TextField(nullable=False)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    # Just some boolean field
    is_big = models.BooleanField(nullable=False)
```

I want to query the number of "big" streets in a country. This is done like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM Street
 INNER JOIN City
    ON Street.city_id = City.id
 WHERE Street.is_big = true AND City.country_id = 'xxxxxxx'::uuid
```

There are a total of around ~20 countries, ~5000 cities and ~2 million streets in the database, which is not a lot, yet this query can take sometimes 1-2 seconds.

What index should I add to make this query fast?

Comment: Index the foreign key and all fields from the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: As usual, you need to analyze [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-explain.html) output of your query to find what is slowing down it in your particular case. An example from [Understanding EXPLAIN](https://blog.bullgare.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/understanding_explain.html) "20 Would an index help here?", where a query with WHERE clause "_needs to read 99.95% of the table. It won't ever use an index in that case_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Street s JOIN
     City c
     ON s.city_id = c.id
WHERE s.is_big = true AND c.country_id = 'xxxxxxx'::uuid;
```

There are two possible approaches for this.  However, I suspect that neither will work really well in all cases -- I am guessing that some countries have lots of big streets.

The first approach is to filter on the big streets:  `street(is_big, city_id)` and `city(id, country_id)`.  The second is to filter on the specific country:  `city(country_id, id)` and `street(city_id, is_big)`.

If the database is static, then the query can use an index-only scan -- assuming the data is "visible".

Comment: I'm not sure what does it even mean

Comment: @user972014 . . . It gives you two sets of indexes to try.